# toggle div element attached to closest class

Tags: jquery, css

Ok not sure why I tried using clossest class in jQuery but still not luck, basically I have a DIV class called SHARE attached to each ARTICLE(POST) for my blog, now when I or any one clicks share I wish for the hidden LI to show-up with additional function ex; facebook, twitter and email sharing.

I made this script which does the trick

```
$j(".share").live("click", function() {
         $j("li").toggle("slow");
});
```

but the problem with above code bit is that it will display all hidden LI elements for all articles how would I go about attaching it to single one?

The code is attached to DIV element inside class="article" as such

```
        <div class="date">$article_d<br><span>$article_m</span></div>
        <div class="share">share
             <ul>
             <li style="margin-left: 5px;display: none;">
                 <a href="$facebook_share">$facebook_share_img</a>
             <a href="$twitter_share">$twitter_share_img</a>
             <a href="$email_share">$email_share_im</a>
             </li>
             </ul>
        </div>
```

P.S. please ingore $j syntax since I am using jQuery with Mootools

Comment: That's not possible. You'll have to give each UL an ID to check on. Which language are you programming in?

Comment: its written with PHP so it will be fairly easy to attach values to elements, as for JS library then its primary jQuery, I only use Mootools for simplicity of animating things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$j(".share").live("click", function() {
   $j(this).find("li").toggle("slow");
});
```

The `find` method will select any `li` element within the clicked `div`. As the `li` elements in your example are descendants of the clicked `div`, this should work fine.

However, note that if you have any other `li` elements within the `div`, they will be affected too.

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/HgTuK/).

Answer (score 0):

you might be able to use [SuperFish](http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/#examples) for this. Superfish is actually for menu nav, but I think the principle of what you are trying to do is the same.